# Link a div to a url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ning

I've recently bought a Ning account. You can't edit any html at all.

The only thing you can do is style the original div's with css.
There's a custom code feature where you can add javascript.

I have a `div` called `xn_bar_menu_branding`. Can this be linked to a url say: `google.com` using javascript?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to click on the `div` to go to a URL?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to do this with JavaScript. Are you sure you are not able to edit the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

If with named you mean that it has an `id="xn_bar_menu_branding"` then you can do

```
$('#xn_bar_menu_branding').click(function(){
  window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
});
```

But this will only work for javascript enabled browsers, and it will also not be good for SEO purposes.

---

If you want the mouse to change to a hand when it hovers the div you can do that with CSS with this rule

```
#xn_bar_menu_branding{ cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#xn_bar_menu_branding').html('<a href="http://google.com>Google.com</a>"');
```

This will replace anything in that div with that id with a link to google